# how to process image in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, e-commerce

i am a beginner in this field. please any buddy can suggest me some site or links through that i can learn image processing.

basically my need is just link e commerce website when we customize item and merge text or image with t-shirt or coffee mug that`s what i have to implement.

reference link:  [see this link to understand  my question i have to implement exectly like this.](http://www.zazzle.com/ampersand_elegance_red_keepsake_pillow-189569012189801628):

Answer (score 0):

As per link shared by you, it seems that you need to write an image processing code in JavaScript which can run on client browser.

For that you need to understand the basics of image operations e.g. contrast enhancement, resize, crop, rotation etc.

For this you can refer to a book of Gonzalez and woods for the fundamentals of image processing.

You also need to know how to code this in JavaScript.